# Why does ext-js add ext-gen12345 to all my td elements, and how to do I stop it?

Tags: extjs

I have used an ext-js grid in a project of mine. I want to build some extra tables and functionality by hand.

It is adding auto-generated id's to some of my elements,  in this case.

How do I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was being very silly, I had left the = out of my id="...." so it was auto generating an Id.